# Store decimal float values (DECFLOAT) in database using db2 and c++

Tags: c++, sql, c, db2

I want to store decimal float values in a table with column of type `DECFLOAT` using db2 library and c++. I understand that `SQLDECIMAL64` and `SQLDECIMAL128` have been added for storing decimal float values. Now to insert data into this `DECFLOAT` column how do I assign value to `SQLDECIMAL64` or `SQLDECIMAL128` as these are unions.

Is there any c++ data type that can be used to store decimal float value in the range of `SQLDECIMAL64` or `SQLDECIMAL128` and that can be inserted in `DECFLOAT`?

Answer (score 0):

As you've already mentioned the data type is a struct and as with all these types they have to be constructed to be used accordingly. There is no C/C++ data type which can be mapped 1:1.

Unfortunately there's no example on how to do this in the DB2 LUW documentation, but there's one in the documentation for zOS:

[Examples of using decimal floating point data](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/com.ibm.db2z11.doc.odbc/src/tpc/db2z_odbcdecfloatexample.dita) should give you an idea how to use it in your code.